# OGM Custom Query using Custom Label

Tags: neo4j, label, neo4j-ogm

I have a Neo4j/OGM Entity `Person` which I mapped to the Label `User` using
`@NodeEntity(label="User)`.
I now want to write a custom Query `MATCH (p:Person) where...`.
As far as I see, there is no way to use my Application-Side Type `Person` instead of the Graph-Side Label `User` like in Hibernate, right?
If there is a way, please explain how to do this, or tell my a key-word to google for.
Same question goes for entity properties.

Thank you.

Update:
Lets say I have a User class like so:

```
@NodeEntity(label="Person")
class User {
@Property(name="username")
   private String name;
   ...
}
```

I've used the Mapping to obtain loose coupling so I can eg. rename the Person and won't affect the Neo4j.
And in the Neo4j there are for example `House`s with Relationships to `User`s.
Now I want to load all Houses, referencing a User with the name "Sven", so the Statement would be `MATCH (h:House)-[:HOLDS]->(p:Person {username:'Sven'})`.
Given, that I might have a huge poject with all the entities in some submodule somewhere else, I might not know, that `User` is mapped to `Person` and the user.`name` is mapped to `username`, so in a Hibernate environment, I would query as `MATCH (h:House)-[:HOLDS]->(u:User {name:'Sven'})`. However in OGM this doesn't seem to work.
There might be a way to solve this architectually but in some projects you don't have this choise.

So the question in the End is: Is there some way to get this to work, or do I really need to know the mapping of every entity i use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways :

- Make your User extend a Person class
- if you need more dynamic labels, the class can contain an `@Labels`annotated list of labels to apply. See [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:node-entity:runtime-managed-labels) for more details

About properties, I don't see how this would be useful. Interested to hear about the use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem I've failed to describe is different from what you understood :-) I've added a more detailed example for better understanding